# how to print error in shell script while executing a vertica query?

Tags: linux, shell, vertica

I want to print the error in assigned variable

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(vertica copy query) # if i got error here 
echo $a
```

Comment: What output you are getting from `echo $a`?

Comment: if copy query is fine means i'm getting how many rows inserted. If i have any error in query means i'm not getting any output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need redirect `stderr` to `stdout` with `2>&1`, then you can get the error if the command have error:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(vertica copy query 2>&1) # if i got error here 
echo $a
```

Comment: if i want to print only error and i don't want to print how many rows are loaded if my statement is true, can you suggest me on this ???

Comment: If mean nothing output if command ok, and error output if command has error, then try `a=$(vertica copy query 2>&1 > /dev/null)`.